# Why would you assign a variable to ""?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, python-3.4

so i'm in the middle of the Python course on the Treehouse website and question asks exactly this:

Create a function named most_classes that takes a dictionary of teachers. Each key is a teacher's name and their value is a list of classes they've taught. most_classes should return the teacher with the most classes.

Here I have posted the correct code below that I have found from a resource on the Treehouse forums and I have asked this same question but got no reply - So what exactly does assigning teacher = "" do? I am so confused

```
 # The dictionary will be something like:
 # {'Jason Seifer': ['Ruby Foundations', 'Ruby on Rails Forms', 'Technology Foundations'],
 #  'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections']}

 # Often, it's a good idea to hold onto a max_count variable.
 # Update it when you find a teacher with more classes than
 # the current count. Better hold onto the teacher name somewhere
 # too!

def most_classes(my_dict):
    count = 0
    teacher = "" #this is where I am confused!
    for key in my_dict: 
        if(len(my_dict[key]) > count):
            count = len(my_dict[key])
            teacher = key   

    return teacher
```

Comment: `teacher = ""` binds `teacher` to an empty string. It is a nice default for when `my_dict` is empty (e.g. the loop will never iterate and no other value is ever assigned to `teacher`).

Comment: Seems like a lot of work just for `max(my_dict, key=lambda x: len(my_dict[x]))`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: you mean `max(my_dict, key=lambda x: len(my_dict[x]), default="")`.

Comment: `default` will work if there are no teachers, but not if the dictionary has teachers with no classes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, TigerhawkT3 you guys are on such another level I don't even understand the codes you guys posted. . lol.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "binds 'teacher' to an empty string" exactly what I needed to know. thanks! :)

Comment: @Raylon: `max()` returns the element with the highest value. When `key` is set it is used to calculate the value for each element, here that's a function that returns the length of the dictionary value. So it finds the key in `mydict` for which the `len()` of the value is highest. `default=""` tells `max()` to return that empty string if there are no keys in `mydict` at all.

Comment: Maybe `any(my_dict.values()) and max(...)`.

Comment: @Raylon: in other words, that one line does exactly the same thing as your function does.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: arguably the function as posted should use `count = -1`...

Comment: @MartijnPieters excellent explanation! Thank you!!! :)

Comment: When i read "list of classes in a dict" I thought this was going to be crazy code.

Answer (score 0):

It's assigning default value to teacher, which will be replaced by the actual teacher name in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`teacher = ""` ensures if `my_dict` is empty you won't exit the for loop without ever setting `teacher = key`. Otherwise, if `my_dict` is empty, `teacher` will be returned without ever having been set.

If you comment out that line, then call your function like this:

`most_classes({})`

You'll get this (since `teacher` never gets initialized before it is returned):

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'teacher' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove that line and test it?

```
def most_classes(my_dict):
    count = 0
    teacher = "" # this is where I am confused!
    for key in my_dict:
        if(len(my_dict[key]) > count):
            count = len(my_dict[key])
            teacher = key

    return teacher


def most_classes_cavalier(my_dict):
    count = 0
    for key in my_dict:
        if(len(my_dict[key]) > count):
            count = len(my_dict[key])
            teacher = key

    return teacher


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dic = {'Jason Seifer': ['Ruby Foundations', 'Ruby on Rails Forms', 'Technology Foundations'],
           'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections']}
    print "The teacher with most classes is - " + most_classes(dic)
    print "The teacher with most classes is - " + most_classes_cavalier(dic)
    dic = {}
    print "The teacher with most classes is - " + most_classes(dic)
    print "The teacher with most classes is - " + most_classes_cavalier(dic)
```

This is what I get when I run the program -

```
The teacher with most classes is - Jason Seifer
The teacher with most classes is - Jason Seifer
The teacher with most classes is -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiment.py", line 30, in <module>
    print "The teacher with most classes is - " + most_classes_cavalier(dic)
  File "experiment.py", line 20, in most_classes_cavalier
    return teacher
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'teacher' referenced before assignment
```

I see that @martijn-pieters has already provided the explanation, but in this case the Python interpreter would have done that for you much quicker.